# Creating a new controller class in Visual Studio with MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I create a new controller in Visual Studio with MVC It generate automatically the following code :

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

My Default1Controller inherit from Controller but I work with a BaseController class and I always have to remember to change the inheritance. Is it possible to  Is it possible to modify or create a new template to automatically generate a more specific code for my project?

```
public class Default1Controller : BaseController
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Thank you,

Comment: You need to override the T4 template and may also use scaffolding for productivity. Link is posted on my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to modify the T4 template that's at the basis of the "Add controller" command.

Go to \Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddController\ (replace with your version of VS and MCV) and modify the Controller.tt

The line `public class <#= mvcHost.ControllerName #> : Controller` should become `public class <#= mvcHost.ControllerName #> : BaseController`

More details can be found on Scott Hanselman's [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You need `custom code generation` in `MVC`.

The following link might be helpful.

> [Modifying the default code generation/scaffolding templates in
>   ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx)

and also

> [ASP.NET MVC and T4 and NerdDinner](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode43ASPNETMVCAndT4AndNerdDinner.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to modify the controller T4 templates located in a folder like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddController
```

Simply change the line

```
public class <#= mvcHost.ControllerName #> : Controller
```

to

```
public class <#= mvcHost.ControllerName #> : BaseController
```

Also, the links provided by Asif are useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the T4 template and may also use scaffolding for productivity. Here us more info : [MvcScaffolding: Overriding the T4 Templates](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/)